# Detect whether sentence contains a word in a file

Tags: bash, input, grep, word-list

When the user enters something, the script is suppose to check if the input contains any of the words from the wordfile.

Input:

```
A sentence that contains the word, word1.
```

Wordfile:

```
word1
word2
word3
```

Code:

```
[[ -z $(cat 'vocabulary/lists/wordfile' | grep -Fe $($input//" "/"\|")) ]]
```

Output:

```
> [WORD]
./core.sh: line 168: [WORD]// /\|: No such file or directory
grep: option requires an argument -- 'e'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
[WORD]
```

Comment: What does your `wordfile` look like? I think that this might be as simple as `grep -Fqf wordfile <<<"$input" && echo 'found a word'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
[[ -n $(sed -n -f <(sed 's/^/\//g;s/$/\/p/g' vocabulary/lists/wordfile) <<< "$input") ]] && echo Found
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that this might be what you need:

```
grep -Fqf wordfile <<<"$input" && echo 'found a word'
```

This does a fixed string match (`-F`) using patterns from the file `wordfile` (`-f wordfile`) and uses `-q` to silently exit successfully if any matches are found.

For example:

```
$ cat wordfile
apple
ball
cat
$ input='a string containing the word ball'
$ grep -Fqf wordfile <<<"$input" && echo 'found a word'
found a word
```

Comment: Simply `grep -Eqf wordfile && echo "found"` might probably work as well

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm not sure I'd call extended regex mode `-E` any simpler than using fixed string mode! ;)

Comment: Oh sure. `-F` can also make sense (and is actually used in the question, thought it was `-E`). I was just pointing out that grep can read `$input` directly.

Comment: ./core.sh: line 181: conditional binary operator expected
./core.sh: line 181: syntax error near `-Fqf'
./core.sh: line 181: `  elif [[ grep -Fqf 'vocabulary/lists/greeting' <<<"$input" ]]'

Comment: You don't need to (shouldn't) use `[[` at all with this command. You can use `if grep -Fqf wordfile <<<"$input"; then...`.